# SQL - No Join Predicate (when there IS JOIN PREDICATES!)

Tags: sql, indexing, warnings, inner-join

Snippit from code:

```
FROM JobsView j
          INNER JOIN  CostItemsView a 
            ON j.BidMasterJobUID = a.BidMasterJobUID
          LEFT JOIN ResourceEmploymentsView b 
            ON a.BidMasterJobUID = b.BidMasterJobUID and a.WbsCode = b.CostItemWbsCode
          LEFT JOIN ResourcesView c 
            ON c.BidMasterJobUID = b.BidMasterJobUID and c.UID = b.ResourceUID
```

Where ResourcesView is causing my "No Join Predicate Warning" on all nested loop inner joins in the view (only started displaying once i rebuilt my indexes)

Code from View:

```
FROM         dbo.Resources AS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.ResourcesCalculatedValues AS b 
  ON b.UID = a.UID AND b.BidMasterJobUID = a.BidMasterJobUID 
INNER JOIN dbo.ResourcesReferencedData AS c 
  ON c.UID = a.UID AND c.BidMasterJobUID = a.BidMasterJobUID
```

Note: This view is used twice in my query and no join predicate warning appears both times.

Also worth mentioning my act vs est rows is way off for all 3 queries in the join 383 act vs 62,302 est. maybe have something to do with it?

Comment: JobsView (first view to be joined on in this subquery). directly right of the FROM statement

Comment: Could it have something to do with i have left joins joining my view which has inner joins used to create the view?  When i change my left joins to inner joins i lose some performance ( a few seconds) but the warnings gone? thoughts?

Comment: Please show the entire queries, DDL and error message. Which SQL? Why no `dbo.` in the first excerpt?